# "Missing $ inserted" No idea why it is saying this

Tags: matrices

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\[
\bf{P}=

\begin{Vmatrix}

P_{00} & P_{01} & P_{02} & \ldots \\
P_{10} & P_{11} & P_{12} & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots\\
P_{i0} & P_{i1} & P_{i2} & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots

\end{Vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site :) You have clear lines within display math mode (`\[ ... \]`) you have to remove them, or comment them out.

Comment: What do you mean by clear lines?

Comment: Blank lines, you have blank empty lines, they're not allowed

Comment: That's okay. Also, avoid `\bf`, `\it`, `\tt` and others. They're 20+ years deprecated. They're also switches, not commands, so if you were to use them, you'd need to use them like `{\bf P}`, `{\it P}` and so on. But you shouldn't use them. You want `\mathbf{P}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have clear lines within display math mode (`\[ ... \]`), you have to remove them

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbf{P} =
  \begin{Vmatrix}
    P_{00} & P_{01} & P_{02} & \ldots \\
    P_{10} & P_{11} & P_{12} & \ldots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots\\
    P_{i0} & P_{i1} & P_{i2} & \ldots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots
  \end{Vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Or comment them out.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbf{P}=
%
  \begin{Vmatrix}
%
    P_{00} & P_{01} & P_{02} & \ldots \\
    P_{10} & P_{11} & P_{12} & \ldots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots\\
    P_{i0} & P_{i1} & P_{i2} & \ldots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots
%
  \end{Vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, avoid `\bf`, `\it`, `\tt` and others. They're 20+ years deprecated. They're also switches, not commands, so if you were to use them, you'd need to use them like `{\bf P}`, `{\it P}` and so on. But you shouldn't use them. You want `\mathbf{P}`.